# Why isn't optimal_count giving the right result?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, igraph

I'm trying to understand python-igraph and specifically the community_walktrap function. I created the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import igraph

mat = np.zeros((200,200)) + 50
mat[20:30,20:30] = 2
mat[80:90,80:90] = 2

g = igraph.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(mat.tolist(),
                                    mode=igraph.ADJ_DIRECTED) 
wl = g.community_walktrap(weights=g.es['weight'])
```

I would have assumed the optimal count of communities to be 3, but running

```
print wl.optimal_count
```

give me 1. If I force the dendrogram to be cut at 3 `wl.as_clustering(3)` I get a membership list that's correct. What am I doing wrong with optimal_count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think the optimal cluster count should be 3? It seems to me that all the nodes have fairly strong connections to each other (they have a weight of 50), except two small groups where the connections are weaker. Note that clustering methods in igraph expect the weights to denote *similarities*, not distances. Also note that most clustering algorithms in igraph are not well-defined for directed networks (some of them even simply reject directed networks).

For what it's worth, `wl.optimal_count` simply calculates the so-called modularity measure (see the `modularity()` method of the `Graph` class) and then picks the cluster count where the modularity is highest. The modularity with only one cluster is zero (this is how the measure works by definition). The modularity with three clusters is around -0.0083, so igraph is right to pick one cluster only instead of three:

```
>>> wl.as_clustering(3).modularity
-0.00829996846600007
>>> wl.as_clustering(1).modularity
0.0
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right- I assumed that the input matrix was setup as a connectivity matrix where high numbers indicate long distances. Normalizing the grid to mat = np.zeros((200,200)) + 1./50 and mat[20:30,20:30] = 1; mat[80:90,80:90] = 1 give me the correct answer.